# How to replace word with bars for desktop menu dropdown

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following html snippet from [this page](https://4309.co.uk)

```
    <div id="title-bar">
  <button id="close-btn" class="tb-buttons">
    <img src="Images/Cl</div>
              <div class="module widget. 
         handle mobile-toggle right 
         visible-sm visible-xs"><i 
                               class="fa fa-bars"></i>. 
                                                 </div><div class="module 
         group right"><div 
                     class="module left">                     
                                        <div class="collapse navbar- 
         collapse navbar-ex1- 
         collapse"><ul id="menu" 
                                class="menu"><li id="menu. 
         item-3530" class="menu-item 
         menu-item-type-post_type 
         menu-item-object-page menu- 
         item-has-children menu-item- 
         3530 dropdown"><a 
                       title="Contact"  
                                      href="https://4309.co.uk
         /contact/">Contact </a><span 
                   class="dropdown-toggle 
         shapely-dropdown" data- 
                          toggle="dropdown"><i 
                                           class="fa 
         fa-angle-down" aria- 
                       hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <ul role="menu" class=" 
         dropdown-menu"><li id="menu- 
         item-2864" class="menu-item 
         menu-item-type-post_type 
         menu-item-object-page menu- 
         item-2864"><a title="Drawing 
         Development"  
                     href="https://4309.co.uk/
         drawing. 
         development/">Drawing 
                      Development</a></li>ose.png" />
  </button>
  <p id="title">CharactersPalette</p>
  <button id="eye-btn" class="tb-buttons">
    <img src="Images/Hide.png" />
  </button>
  <button id="min-btn" class="tb-buttons">
    <img src="Images/Min.png" />
  </button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replace the word `contact` with menu bars in desktop. It shows as bars in mobile but not desktop. I'm assuming answer is php but other ways considered.

I'm new to php so I not sure what file controls homepage. I found `home. php in my public html-theme and found this inside it.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || ! 
dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-home' ) ) :
?><div class="container p24 wp-caption-text">
<h5><?php echo esc_html__( 'This is the "Home Sidebar 
 Section", add some widgets to it to change it.', 'shapely' ); 
 ?></h5></<div>
 <?php endif; ?><?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But no indication of menu...

I've got this far with css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {#menu-item-3530 
{display:none;}}
```

Php failing, can I do some sort of `before after` here? I'm assuming that I'd need to add a button function to make it drop down, can this also be done using only css?

Comment: well a brute-force approach would be to redesign #menu-item-3530 via CSS give it a background and text color transparent. with conditional CSS based on screen width

Comment: @GeorgeDryser OK. So media query and then.....

Comment: yep, I guess you don't want to change the widget JS itself..

Comment: Well I was hoping for some sort of php solution. Conditional so `if screen width over 768px then continue to display bars` Css and php are best options I think.

Comment: `<? php get_header(); ?>
<?php
if ( ! menu bars etc.... `

Comment: `So your saying @media (min-width: 768px) {#menu-item- 330 {something before, something after}}`?

Comment: @georgedryser I've got this far `@media (min-width: 768px) {#menu-item-3530 {display:none;}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the string which contains the settings in `header.php`

So go to: `cpanel-file manager- public html-wp-content-themes-yourtheme`

Once there select `header.php` and you will find a string containing:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header<?php echo 
get_theme_mod( 'mobile_menu_on_desktop', false ) ? ' 
 mobile-menu' : ''; ?>" role="banner">
```

Or something like it.

Change the `false` to `true` and you have your mobile menu on desktop like so:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header<?php echo 
get_theme_mod( 'mobile_menu_on_desktop', true ) ? ' 
mobile-menu' : ''; ?>" role="banner">
```